# EF Code First: model type is not pluralized in the repository

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ef-code-first, code-first, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding

I have a `State` model class:

```
public class State
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int CountryId { get; set; }
    public virtual Country Country { get; set; }
}
```

And I am trying to create a `Repository`:

```
Scaffold Repository State
```

I've got in generated file:

```
public IQueryable<State> All
{
    get { return context.State; }
}
```

instead of `context.StateS`.

Property

```
public DbSet<State> States { get; set; }
```

successfully has been added to the `DbContext` class.

I have no overrided `OnModelCreating` method.

Sometimes I mention such problem in different projects but can not find a reason.

Answer (score 0):

I know I've had problems with namespace confusion when using the word "State" for my database tables and POCOs.  So to make things easier, I rename those to something else, like USState or StateCode.  That could be what's going on here for you and the scaffolding.